# What are the Results of the First and Second Axioms of Countability?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, intuition

What are the consequences of a space being first or second countable? What was the motivation for these axioms in the first place?

Comment: These are properties that really smooth out pathological topological spaces. Without placing these restrictions (not having a countable local base! what?!), the topological spaces become so fine grained that you can't really do any of the usual analysis you'd want to do. Placing these restrictions allows you to actually come up with meaningful results. Second countability is a very strong condition (but very nice); first countability is a little strong but many topological spaces we see in practice are first countable so it isn't that strong of a restriction.

Comment: In fact, you can show that many things you'd *like* to be true are equivalent to ___ + first countability or ____ + second countability.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: why do not you expand your comment into an answer. It will be useful to users like me.

Answer (score 1):

From a point of view of a general topologist, these spaces are nice. For topologists which work with cardinal invariants, many of them collapse for these spaces. By Tichonoff-Urysohn Theorem, a [second countable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) is metrizable iff it is regular (in this case it is homeomorphic to a subspace of the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$). First countable spaces are rarely metrizable$^\star$, but, nevertheless, in these spaces a closure can be defined by convergent sequences. First (and second too) countable spaces are preserved by open continuous maps. In fact, by Ponomarev Theorem, each first-countable space of infinite cardinality is an open continuous image of a zero-dimensional metrizable space of the same weight.

$^\star$ But, by Birkhoff-Kakutani Theorem, a $T_0$ topological group is metrizable iff it is first countable.